# How to set QModelIndex to QListView

Tags: qt

Im really a noob at QT so go easy on me 
So i have 2 QListviews
1. TimeList
2. DateList
What im trying to Do is that when i select an item in Timelist the same index in Datelist will be selected and after that i will send the data to a datetime edit

I tried to use that QAbstractItemmodel model->index(row,column);
and createindex but i dont know syntax that well so i messed it up

```
QModelIndex i = ui->TimeList->currentIndex(); //it gets the index when an item is clicked
ui->DateList->setcurrentIndex(i); //it sets the same index in the other QListView
ui->DateList->clearSelection();
ui->DateList->selectionModel()->select(i, QItemSelectionModel::Select); //This highlights the same index in other QListView and it works fine


QTime t = i.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toTime(); // It converts to QTime fine
i = ui->DateList->currentindex(); // i try to change the value of index to get the date
QDate d = i.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toDate(); 

ui->TimeEdit->setTime(t);
ui->DateEdit->setDate(d);
```

What i have gathered is that i.data output is invalid for QDate because it says so in qDebug so.
So i suppose index doesnt only hold row and column values but how to assign it to Datelist is beyond me. (:
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with *same index*? Do you mean items that are in the same row or that show the same text?

Comment: @eyllanesc items that are in the same row so that if row 1 is selected in first list row 1 will be selected in second list

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to learn syntax to create a new QIndexModel

```
QModelIndex i = ui->TimeList->currentIndex();
QModelIndex i2 = ui->DateList->model()->index(i.row(), 0);
```

So i use the same row value from index1 but its assigned to the second QListview